# Spawned application in Electron opens dialog behind electron app window instead of in front

Tags: node.js, printing, dialog, electron

I have an application that was previously written in Flex and AIR. This application would start up three child processes using the [AIR Native Process API](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/desktop/NativeProcess.html). Two are DotNet applications and one is a java applet. When AIR would start the applications they would show as individual processes in the details tab of task manager and also as sub processes of the AIR application in the Processes tab as shown below

[image]
[image]
[image]

The POSPrint application is a printing application that we send requests to and when a request was sent, if no default printer is set it will open the standard windows dialog to choose a printer and you could click cancel or ok as normal.

We are in the process of migrating this application to Electron and Angular.

Originally I was spawning the processes using a node module called cross-spawn but for some reason we had problems sending requests to the spawned application, it would receive the request but then it would do nothing with it.

We then used the normal node child_process module and used execFile to launch the applications. This allowed us to send our requests (we actually send http requests to the java applet as a middleware and the java applet speaks to POSPrint). These requests are reaching POSPrint and the dialog is now launching using this approach of launching the applications. The problem is that in the Electron application, the dialog is opening behind the Electron application and a user must alt+tab or move windows around in order to see the dialog.

At first it was thought that it was because we were using 64-bit Electron and launching a 32-bit POSPrint application, but after we created a 32-bit version as well, we were still unable to get the dialog to show up in front. We've also tried the other ways of spawning processes via spawn and exec but the dialog will never open in front of the Electron application.